# ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The > content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a > notification

Tags: java, android

I get this error, when i try to change my orientation and also calling my Async Activity. The user clicks on `refresh to get data and he tries to change the orientation`, i get this error.

I looked back at my code.... i am calling the `notifyDataSetChanged` method only in `onPostExecute()`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    adapater.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Logcat

```
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):
  slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:476)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754) 06-12 18:19:11.777:
  E/XXX(10529):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754) 06-12 18:19:11.777:
  E/XXX(10529):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754) 06-12 18:19:11.777:
  E/XXX(10529):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-12 18:19:11.777:
  E/XXX(10529):     at
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-12 18:19:11.777:
  E/XXX(10529):     at
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
  06-12 18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):     at
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558) 06-12
  18:19:11.777: E/XXX(10529):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
   Method)
```

My doInBackgroundClass

```
@
Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String...params) {
    if (Utils.UpdateDate(params)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you update the Adapter's data set inside `doInBackgound` of your async task?

Comment: **Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
  from a background thread, but only from the UI thread**. this is your clue to the error. post your doInbackground()

Comment: Updated the same.... and Utils a separate class which makes the Async Call...

Comment: Utils.UpdateDate(params) what does this do?

Comment: Utils a separate class which makes the Async Call... which returns a boolean

Comment: post that part of the code where you get data and add the same to listview

Comment: In onCreate i am adding it to List View, but on refresh i am just updating the data alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31664/discussion-between-thejava-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 1):

Move your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call from the `onPostExecute()` method to whatever method you modify the the adapter.

Comment: I am not getting this at all, what method where i modify??

Comment: @theJava you will have to post some relevant code where you get data and the same to listview

Comment: In what method do you modify(add, remove, re-order elements) your adapter? You should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` immediately after modifying the adapter in any way.